# trying to generate a link from mysql using html

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query and i am trying to create an extra column with the href link inside it, what is wrong i am doing here

```
SELECT
    Id AS ID,
    keywords AS keywords,
    '<a href="'javascript:;'" class="'DELETE'" data-id="'+ id +'">Delete</a>' AS 'Delete' 
FROM
    tblkeywords
```

error I am getting is:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ':' at line 4

Comment: You need to check the documentation on how to concatenate strings in the DBMS you are using before writing some code. [`CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) or [`CONCAT_WS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) with [string literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html) will help you. It is hard to tell where is table field and where is string part. Please, add more description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `concat` function:

```
SELECT
    Id AS ID,
    keywords AS keywords,
    CONCAT('<a href="''javascript:;''" class="DELETE" data-id="', id,'">Delete</a>' AS 'Delete' 
FROM
    tblkeywords
```